# Login com verificação de duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site, e ando com bastante dúvidas ultimamente, é para o meu tcc e eles auxiliam pouco.

Fiz um sistema para cadastrar o usuário sendo aluno ou professor com MySQL, em diferentes tabelas.
Exemplo: se o usuário for aluno, ele entra na aba de cadastro do aluno e esses dados são enviados para a tabela aluno, bem como se o usuário for professor. Até ai tudo bem.

Porém com o sistema de login, preciso que ele verifique o email e senha das duas tabelas (aluno e professor);
Estou tento problemas com isso, pois do jeito que fiz ele retorna email ou senha incorretas.

Segue o código php abaixo da validação do usuário:

```
 <?php

 session_start();
 include("conexao.php");

 $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 /* Verifica se existe usuario, o segredo ta aqui quando ele procupa uma
 linha q contenha o login e a senha digitada */
 $sql_logar = "SELECT aluno.email, aluno.senha, professor.email, professor.senha 
 FROM aluno, professor WHERE aluno.email AND professor.email = '$email' AND aluno.senha AND professor.senha = '$senha'";
 $exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error($conection));
 $num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

 //Verifica se n existe uma linha com o login e a senha digitado
 if ($num_logar == 0){

     $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
     header("Location: index.php?login");
 }
 else{
     //Cria a sessão e verifica tipo de login
     $informacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);

     $_SESSION['tipo'] = $informacao ['tipo'];
     $_SESSION['email'] = $informacao ['email'];
     $_SESSION['senha'] = $informacao ['senha']; 
     $_SESSION['nome'] = $informacao ['nome'];


     if($_SESSION['tipo'] != "2"){
         header("Location: aluno.php");
     }else{
     header("Location: professor.php");
     }
 }
?>
```

Observa-se na conexão do MySQL baixo que tentei realizar com que ele selecione os respectivos emails e senhas das duas tabelas, porém não funcionou, ele retorna que os dados de login inseridos pelo usuário estão **incorretos**.

> **$sql_logar = "SELECT aluno.email, aluno.senha, professor.email, professor.senha FROM aluno, professor WHERE aluno.email AND professor.email = '$email' AND aluno.senha AND professor.senha = '$senha'";**

Se alguém souber de alguma maneira melhor de fazer Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Do php não consigo ajudar mas eu faria uma tabela usuários, e outra usuarios_perfil e nessa segunda iria controlar os usuários, acho que a modelagem fica melhor assim

Comment: Pensei na mesma coisa @rnd_rss, porém queria organizar de forma mais completa, para que quando eu quiser ver quais professores não preciso procurar na tabela de usuários.

Comment: Entendi, seria bom dar uma olhada em normalização de dados pra você entender melhor porque separar, e se for pra ficar mais "fácil" coloca tudo em uma só tabela e cria uma coluna perfil

Comment: Ta bom, se caso ninguém conseguir ajudar, irei fazer desta forma!

Comment: Refaça a modelagem pois mesmo concertando a consulta o problema gerado é muito maior:  `SELECT aluno.email, aluno.senha, professor.email, professor.senha 
 FROM aluno, professor WHERE (aluno.email = '$email'  OR professor.email = '$email') AND (aluno.senha = '$senha' OR professor.senha = '$senha');` .Desculpe-me usar o termo, mas isso é conhecido informalmente como estilo gambi de codificação(gambiarra) e não é uma coisa boa. É como uma bola de neve onde a cada nova funcionalidade você precise utilizar uma código cada vez maior para sanear o problema criado na raiz.

Comment: Até que deu certo @AugustoVasques, porém como você disse, isso acarreta em vários problemas, acho que irei resolver tudo isso com apenas uma tabela. Não há muito o que se fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido da seguinte forma. Criei uma tabela usuários para generalizar todos os cadastrados no sistema, sendo assim. Fui atribuído um novo campo com o nome "tipo" para determinar qual seria a função do usuário no site.

```
$sql_logar = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, senha, confsenha, email, nomecomp, matricula, tipo)
```

Junto a isso, também modifiquei que, para no final, adicionar um número para determinar a função, sendo possível a alteração no futuro.

```
VALUES ('$usuario_aluno', '$senha_aluno', '$confsenha_aluno', '$email_aluno', '$nomecomp_aluno', '$matricula_aluno', '1')";
```